# How to convert multidimensional PHP array to html table

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, html-table

I'm trying to make a HTML table out of a multidimensional array variable `$array2` which is a query(from a mysql database PHP query and Not a self-made query)  and is as follows;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => M2TYEE
            [1] => Jean
            [2] => Harvey
            [3] => London
            [4] => 0314686334
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => E26YBE
            [1] => Tom
            [2] => Cruise
            [3] => New York
            [4] => 0635625735     
        )

)
```

I want to make the table appear like this

```
|ID     |FIRST NAME| LAST NAME |  CITY     | PHONE      |
________________________________________________________
|M2TYEE | Jean     |  Harvey   |  London   | 0314686334 |
--------------------------------------------------
|E26YBE | Tom      |  Cruise   |  New York | 0635625735 |
```

They array may increase to upto say 1000 values so using a while/for loop would be necessary.
Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_merge` and `foreach` for the desired output

```
$arr = array_merge([ 0 => ['ID','FIRST NAME','LAST NAME','CITY','PHONE']],$arr);
$html = '<table border="1">';
foreach($arr as $row){
  $html .= '<tr>';
  foreach($row as $column){
    $html .= '<td>'.$column.'</td>';
  }
  $html .= '</tr>'; 
}
$html .= '</table>';
echo $html;
```

Comment: Works amazingly perfect but change the first line to `$arr = array_merge([ 0 => ['ID','FIRST NAME','LAST NAME','CITY','PHONE']],$array2);`

Answer (score 0):

because your internal array are fixed with size ( all have 4 field) , you can use single loop as below:

```
echo "<table>";
foreach($array2 as $index){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$index[0]."</td><td>".$index[1]."</td><td>".$index[2]."</td><td>".$index[3]."</td><td>".$index[4]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Another approach:

```
$result.="<table>";
foreach($array2 as $index){
    $result.="<tr>";
    $result.="<td>".$index[0]."</td><td>".$index[1]."</td><td>".$index[2]."</td><td>".$index[3]."</td><td>".$index[4]."</td>";
    $result.="</tr>";
}
$result.="</table>";
echo $resul;
```

Comment: Doesn't work quite well but very helpful. Thank you

Comment: @KalisploitTutorials, you can only add `<tr><th>Your Header title</th></tr>` for every field.